# JPA How to get a property from a Arraylist of objects in a ManyToMany relation

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Im struggling on how to get a attribute from a arraylist filled with objects. I want to find all the Dishes that belong to a certain Meal and filter those by the dishType and display them in a table in the view.

So I have written the method getDishNameByType but it will return null. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Meal.Java**

```
public class Meal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Dish> dishesList = new HashSet<>();


    public String getDishNameByType(String dishType) {  
        for (Dish dish : dishesList) {
            if (dishType == dish.getDishType()) {
                return dish.getDishName();
            }
        }
        return null;    
    }
}
```

**Dish.Java**

```
public class Dish {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;   

    private String dishName;

    private String dishType;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "dishesList")
    private Set<Meal> mealsList = new HashSet<>();
```

**View.html**

```
<tr th:if="${mealPage.empty}">
    <td colspan="7" th:text="#{meals.list.table.empty}">No meals found</td>
</tr>
<tr th:each="meal : ${mealPage}">
    <td th:text="${meal.id}">1</td>
    <td th:each="dish : ${meal.dishesList}"
    th:text="${meal.getDishNameByType("Maincourse")}"></td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two objects, `obj1` and `obj2`, then `obj1 == obj2` will be `true` if and only if the two objects are the very same.

```
String foo = "abc";
String bar = "abc";

boolean same = (foo == bar); //false
boolean similar = (foo.equals(bar)); //true
```

So you will need to call `equals`:

```
public String getDishNameByType(String dishType) {  
    for (Dish dish : dishesList) {
        if ((dishType.equals(dish.getDishType()))) {
            return dish.getDishName();
        }
    }
    return null;    
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I've forgot about the difference between a String and Int there.
But I've still got a problem in the view at th:text="${meal.getDishNameByType(Maincourse)}" I get the error: Can't resolve Maincourse

Comment: @Bram you have this code: "${meal.getDishNameByType("Maincourse")}". I am not a Hibernate user, but it seems that you have a problem with the quote. It seems you need to escape that. I think "${meal.getDishNameByType(\"Maincourse\")}" might help you, but I do not know, however, I'm convinced that the problem is with the quote being interpreted as the closing of the value.

Comment: Thanks alot! the quotes were indeed interpreted as closing values. I've got it to work using single quotes: th:text="${meal.getDishNameByType('Maincourse')}" .

Comment: @Bram you've managed to solve this one on your own. Excellent.